How to fix the code sign key not found issue in Azure pipeline in MAUI .net 8.0-iOS?
I have enterted the code provision profile and code sign key in my cs proj like below
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' "><DebugType>none</DebugType>

<Optimize>true</Optimize>

<OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Release</OutputPath>

<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>

<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>

<RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>

<ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>

<CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution: Companyname, Inc. (USER ID)</CodesignKey>

<CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>

<CodesignProvision>MyAppProvision</CodesignProvision>

<CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage> </PropertyGroup>

But when I run in Azure pipeline under DotNet publish task it shows as No Valid ios code signing key found in keychain.
Also I have added like this in DotNet publish task Argument as -p:CodesignKey="iPhone Distribution: Companyname, Inc. (USER ID)" , but returns error as Switch: Distribution or error: Property not valid Switch: Inc. (USER ID)

Was your pipeline running on a Microsoft-hosted or self-hosted macOS agent to build your MAUI project? If using a self-hosted agent, it seemed that the apple developer .p12certificate was not installed on that machine.

Hi @AjitK, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to install .p12 certificate during pipeline build? Hope it can resolve your issue in this post. Thx for your time and sharing.

I tried but my code sign key having (,) comma in middle which is detected the code sign key as before comma alone and not including the key after comma

Did the issue fail the InstallAppleCertificate@2 task? What was the output if you run bash: echo "APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY is $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)" after certificate installation?

I am getting as APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY is iPhone Distribution: Companyname, Inc. (USER ID) in that Bash task

I am thinking what if directly using <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution: Companyname, Inc. (USER ID)</CodesignKey> in your .csproj without passing -p:CodesignKey="$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)". By the way, were you using the Microsoft-hosted agent to run the this pipeline? Was the issue reproducible if you ran dotnet publish on local Mac?

Yeah in dotnet publish only , also when I ran in cs proj it is saying no valid signing certificate found

So the value of $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY) was correct in bash. It seemed necessary to escape value in dotnetCLI. Would you try with -p:CodesignKey="\"$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)\"" as suggested here.

Hi @AjitK, I have updated the answer according to my test and I can see the , is escaped when passing -p:CodesignKey="\"$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)\"". Hope it works for your as well. Good luck with the work to go!

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT I am able to fix this by following the given link thanks for your valuable reply and efforts. Thank you so much

Update
Per the follow-up issue that the CodesignKey argument was not correctly passed due to the comma , in the certificate identity,

we could escape value by adding \" to $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY). Here is sample syntax for DotNetCoreCLI@2 task.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build iOS App
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    arguments: >
      -f net8.0-ios -c Release
      -p:ApplicationDisplayVersion=${{ parameters.ApplicationDisplayVersion }} -p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildId)
      -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64
      -p:CodesignKey="\"$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)\"" -p:CodesignProvision="$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)"
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false



I could reproduce the same error when the .p12 apple developer certificate was not installed on the build agent, for example, the macOS-14 Microsoft-hosted agent.

You may try the steps below to export and upload the certificate to pipeline Library, so that we can install the required secure files during the build.

Export the apple developer .p12 certificate from Keychain Access app of the user's Mac; keep note of the password when saving the .p12 certificate;

Upload the certificate via Pipelines -> Library - Secure file;

Add a secret pipeline variable for the secure $(P12PWD);
Add the task InstallAppleCertificate@2 to retrieve and install the certificate during pipeline build; you may also need to upload and install the provisioning profile with InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1 task;

stages:
- stage: BuildiOS
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: BuildiOS
    pool:
      vmImage: macOS-14
    steps:
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'appledeveloper.p12'
        certPwd: '$(P12PWD)'
        keychain: 'temp'

    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: 'DotNetMauiAppDemoProfile.mobileprovision'
    
    - bash: |
        echo "APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY is $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)"
        echo "APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID is $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)"
      displayName: Check profile
        
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: .NET Version
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '${{ parameters.DotNetVersion }}'
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Install MAUI
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          dotnet nuget locals all --clear 
          dotnet workload install maui --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build iOS App
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.sln'
        arguments: >
          -f net8.0-ios -c Release
          -p:ApplicationDisplayVersion=${{ parameters.ApplicationDisplayVersion }} -p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildId)
          -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64
          -p:CodesignKey="$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)" -p:CodesignProvision="$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)"
        zipAfterPublish: false
        modifyOutputPath: false


We can check the values for the two variables $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY) and $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID) generated by the two tasks in above step and pass them as arguments -p:CodesignKey="$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)" -p:CodesignProvision="$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)" of dotnet publish;

Please find more details in this document to Sign your Apple iOS, macOS, tvOS, or watchOS app.

